# How to join multiple crossfilter datasets with each other?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

There are two datasets, which have a common column (like: cid) for joining them.

Example:

```
var data1 =
cid id  status
11  123 very good,
12  124 good,
13  125 bad,
14  126 average,
15  127 average,
16  128 bad,
17  129 good,
18  130 bad,


var data2 =     
cid cname   cloc    nos
11  IIT delhi   20000,
12  IIM bangalore   40000,
13  NIT patna   120000,
14  ISM dhanbad 10000,
15  JNU delhi   55000,
16  SRM chennai 19000,
```

I want to define dimension and group like so:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(final_data);
var dim_pie = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.status;});  
var fact_pie = dim_pie.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.nos;});
```

How can I join these two cross-filter data-sets? Please explain with some script like data-path, cross-filter, dimension and group.

Comment: You should probably just join the data before you create your Crossfilter.

Comment: Thank you.! But, Can you give me one more help how can i join using cross filter. (like : cid  id  status  cname   cloc    nos ) 

And If, at the place of given Data-set (data1, data2) there are two API address then how can join both API.